# Kubernetes error:- server doesn't have a resource type "logs"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am getting error when I try to deploy kubernetes resource as below:

```
suv@Suvankars-MacBook-Pro[8:50:09]:~/thermeon/gke-staging-envs/charts$ helm install --name=postfix postfix 
NAME:   postfix
LAST DEPLOYED: Sun Jul 12 20:50:15 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/Service
NAME     AGE
postfix  2s

==> v1beta2/Deployment
postfix  2s

==> v1/Pod(related)

NAME                     READY  STATUS             RESTARTS  AGE
postfix-bdc88887f-4bp8q  0/1    ContainerCreating  0         2s


NOTES:
1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
     NOTE: It may take a few minutes for the LoadBalancer IP to be available.
           You can watch the status of by running 'kubectl get svc -w postfix'
  export SERVICE_IP=$(kubectl get svc --namespace default postfix -o jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')
  echo http://$SERVICE_IP:25



suv@Suvankars-MacBook-Pro[8:50:39]:~/thermeon/gke-staging-envs/charts$ kubectl get svc -w postfix
NAME      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
postfix   LoadBalancer   10.1.22.218   <pending>     25:31916/TCP   27s
^C%                                                                                                                                                                    suv@Suvankars-MacBook-Pro[8:50:58]:~/thermeon/gke-staging-envs/charts$ 
suv@Suvankars-MacBook-Pro[8:50:59]:~/thermeon/gke-staging-envs/charts$ 
suv@Suvankars-MacBook-Pro[8:50:59]:~/thermeon/gke-staging-envs/charts$ 
suv@Suvankars-MacBook-Pro[8:51:03]:~/thermeon/gke-staging-envs/charts$ kubectl get pods
NAME                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
postfix-bdc88887f-4bp8q   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2          50s
suv@Suvankars-MacBook-Pro[8:51:21]:~/thermeon/gke-staging-envs/charts$ kubectl get logs postfix-bdc88887f-4bp8q
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "logs"
```

Comment: ```suv@Suvankars-MacBook-Pro[8:51:03]:~/thermeon/gke-staging-envs/charts$ kubectl get pods
NAME                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
postfix-bdc88887f-4bp8q   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2          50s
suv@Suvankars-MacBook-Pro[8:51:21]:~/thermeon/gke-staging-envs/charts$ kubectl get logs postfix-bdc88887f-4bp8q
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "logs"
```

Answer (score 4):

[Kubectl's Official Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/) covers kubectl syntax, describes the command operations, and provides common examples.

> `logs`  `kubectl logs POD [-c CONTAINER] [--follow] [flags]` Print the logs for a container in a pod.

You can always check `kubectl`'s commands (and syntax examples) with commands like:

```
$ kubectl --help
$ kubectl get --help
$ kubectl logs --help
```

and so on.

In this very case it is needed to run

```
kubectl logs postfix-bdc88887f-4bp8q
```

Hope that explains it and gives insight on where to get the further info.

Answer (score 1):

Logs is not a resource in kubernetes so to get logs of a pod you should not specify `get` in the command as shown in  below example.

```
kubectl logs postfix-bdc88887f-4bp8q
```